# Question on Geometry and cyclic circles

Tags: geometry

Two circles intersect at $P$ and $Q$.Through $P$ two lines $APB$ and $CPD$ are drawn to intersect circles at $A,B,C,D$. $AC$ and $DB$ when produced meet at $O$. How do I prove that $OAQB$ is cyclic quadrilateral. Please if possible first give me image so that I can also try it, I can't draw its figure properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your picture at least. The green circle goes through your 4 points.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this figure, I solved this problem.Thanx again!!

Comment: @Ayushakj: Could you post your solution ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

@Lucian
In $\triangle PQB$ $\angle1 + \angle5=\angle3 + \angle4$.
In $\triangle PDB$ $\angle 2 + \angle 3 + \angle PDB=180^o$.Further $\angle2 +\angle3=\angle5$. We have $\angle5=\angle3 + \angle4 - \angle1$. Our previous result become $\angle2 +\angle3=\angle3 + \angle4 - \angle1$. Solving this we derive to $\angle 2 +\angle 1=\angle 4$.This prove $\angle OAQ + \angle OBQ=180^o$[image]